# Is "ĝi estas bona" abbreviated to "estas bona" or "estas bone"?

Tags: abbreviations

I had an discussion on this question earlier, where I thought it would be *estas bona*, since despite *ĝi* being omitted, we're still talking about "it".

Some more experienced speaker said it is *estas bone* because *estas* is now the only verb, and that's how it works in Esperanto.

The discussion would've ended there, but I could swear I saw something like *estas bona* on Duolingo. Did I misremember, or are my friends being too strict with grammar?

Comment: Are you sure it's technically even an abbreviation, though? I know that phrases like just "dankon" and "saluton" are abbreviations for certain phrases (IIRC), but I seem to recall that impersonal verbs don't take subjects in Esperanto. What "it" are you referring to? A physical object? A concept? Nothing?

Comment: I know it doesn't clearly answer to your question but is it possible to abbreviate it directly to "_Bonas_"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an interesting and puzzling phenomenon I started exploring some time a go and still have not yet reached a conclusion, so I'll give more of an impression here than solid evidence.

The rule in fact is that with a single verb without nominal subject (noun, pronoun, citation, or relative clause) the predicative adjective should become an adverb:

> Dancado estas bela ←→ Danci estas bele
>
> La nokto estas malvarma ←→ Estas malvarme

Subjectless verbs like in the second example do not have a clear reference, they just name a state/action.

In case of an ellipsis which refers to a noun named just before, however, there should be no problem to stay with the adjective:

> A: Kaj la vetero?
>
> B: [La vetero/Ĝi/Tiu] Estos certe bona!

A problem rises when the reference is not a clear object, but rather a whole sentence or a situation. Traditionally *tio* or *ĝi* was used as a subject in such cases:

> Tro multe da homoj mortas pro malpurigo de la trinkakvo. Ĝi/Tio estas vere problema.

It seems to me that there is a tendency in modern speech to omit the pronoun in such cases, switching to the adverbial form instead of the adjectival one - although this is not how subjectless verbs were intended.

An explanation for this may be that in early Esperanto *ĝi* was used, as in English, to express an empty subject with atypical subjects (*Ĝi estis varmega posttagmezo* "It was a hot afternoon"). This has (rightly) totally dropped out of use, perhaps taking some of the justified uses with it.

Comment: Are you saying that, without a context, it should be an adverb, but if the context makes it clear, it can stay an adjective? except the last exception

Comment: Yes, in case you just supplement the previous sentence (like you do in other cases like "A: Nun ni bezonas nur... B: La bileton!"), an adjective should be fine, in other cases, or generally when you're not sure go with the adverb.